# created gui from other class not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have two gui classes, Mall and Store. By running the Mall class, a gui is created having a bunch of other buttons including the "store" button. When the "store" button is clicked, a separate window will be created for the store gui. Basically, the Mall class calls the Store constructor when the "store" button is clicked.

When the Store constructor is called from the Mall class, the gui from Store was displayed. But nothing happens when I try to press the arrow buttons. here is my Mall class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mall extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    public static Customer c = new Customer("James");
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // only used to show dialog boxes
    private JPanel panel;    
    //and other private JLabels, ImageIcons, and JButtons

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mall(); 
    }

    public Mall() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        // and initialization of gui components
        store.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(panel);
        // panel.add(....); etc.
    }
    @Override // and other method implementations
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if(menuSelection == 1) {
                new Store(c);   
            }
            // other conditions
        }
        // and other conditions
    }
}
```

Here's my Store class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Store implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame(); 
    private JPanel panel1;    
    //and other private JLabels, ImageIcons, and JButtons

    // works fine if I have this method, but I want it to be called from the Mall class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Store(new Customer("Bon")); }

    public Store(Customer c1) {
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame1.setTitle("Store");
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        // and initialization of gui components
        frame1.addKeyListener(this);
        frame1.add(panel1);
        // panel1.add(....); etc.
    }
    @Override // and other method implementations
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if(storeSelection==1) {
                highlighter.setBounds(100,50,50, 50); // just for highlighting a button
            // other conditions 
        }
        // and other conditions
    }
}
```

The  Mall class works perfectly fine in my code. The Store class also works fine, IF the main method in the Store class is called. Only the Store constructor is reached when it is called from the Mall class (ie. only the graphics). I want to know how to make the Store gui functional when called from the Mall class.

Edit:

behaviors:

The Store gui works if there is a main method from the Store class (public        static void main(String[] args){ new Store(new Customer("James"));})

but the store gui only displays the gui and not functioning (such as if a button is pressed) when the Mall class calls it

question: how can I make the Store class work when called from the Mall class?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question. You basically want us to assist you in making it possible to access the Store from your Mall class? When the "Store" button is clicked?

Comment: @TejjD I have a Mall gui that has a "store" button. If I clicked it, a Store gui should appear. the store gui also has buttons. In my code, the Store gui appeared but it's not responsive when I try to click any buttons or press any keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are showing us, there doesn't seem to be any inconsistencies.

What I can recommend, just for the purpose of testing if it works is:

> Create a JButton, and assign an Action Performed so that it calls the Store Class

```
JButton button = new JButton("Test");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Store(c);
    }
}
```

---

If this works, we can establish that there is an issue with your KeyPressed Event Handler, and then we can take it forward from there.

Else what you can do if the button does work is, use the button instead of a Key Event on the RadioButton group. For example:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Test");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(menuSelection == 1) {
            new Store(c);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Hope this answers your question!

Let me know of the outcome.

Comment: oh, wow. my code is working now. Thank you and I apologize if you didn't understand my problem at first.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could have been of assistance, however little it may have been. Good luck further!